# EF6: Setting DataGridView's DataSource to an EF-Entity results in loading its children as well. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, lazy-loading

I am trying to keep this as short as possible:

I have a simple database with some tables:
artists, albums, songs.

1. artists may have multiple albums. albums may have been created by multiple artists (many-to-many).
2. albums may have multiple songs but one song is limited to one album (1-to-many).

The EntityFramework puts these tables into classes just fine. Now I'm binding my DbContext instance to a DataGridView in a Windows Forms C# project:

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
db.Artists.Include(a => a.Albums).Load(); // include children albums as well
artistBindingSource.DataSource = db.Artists.Local.ToBindingList();
```

The DataGridView instance displays the content correctly. I can save changes and the like.

If the user clicks on a cell (with an artist's name) in the DataGridView, I am loading the related albums by assigning the second DataGridView (with albumBindingSource) to the artist's albums collection:

```
Artist a = (Artist)row.DataBoundItem; // row contains selected grid row
if (a != null)
{
    albumBindingSource.DataSource = a.Albums;
}
```

This also works ok, but when debugging the SQL statements I found something peculiar:
When assigning the second DataGridView's DataSource to a.albums (that is the selected instance's albums), Entity Framework also lazy loads the album's songs in multiple SELECT statements (one for each song).

**Question 1:** Why is it loading the albums' children as well? I never told it to do so.

---

However: if I add the following code to the line where the entities are preloaded, the lazy loading disappears:

```
db.Artists.Include(c => c.Albums.Select(b => b.Songs)).Load();
```

**Question 2:** Do I really need to preload ALL children and grandchildren in order to prevent the lazy loading? I never wanted the grandchildren to appear in my Windows Form.

**Question 3:** (see Q.2) Why is it "include" and then "select"? I think something like...

```
db.Artists.Include(c => c.Albums.Include(d => d.Songs)).Load();
```

...would be way more intuitive.

Anyway: thanks for helping me out here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is loading entities probably because *LazyLoading* is turned on. You can turn of *LazyLoading* by `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` no need to load everything. Aditionally, there is two `Include` methods (not counting *overloads*). One is method of `DbQuery<TEntity>` and `DbSet<TEntity>` inherits it, so you can see `Include` method for your sets, another is in `QuerableExtensions` class, which is extension method of `IQuerable<T>`, which in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace. So it is written for `IQuerable` and you specify collection childrens using `Select` method.

Comment: Thanks Adil, that did the trick. But there's one thing that I still cannot understand: if I call only db.Artists.Load(); at the beginning, no lazy loading is done. The SELECT statement contains just the artists table. But if I bind the second DataGridView to a.Albums, the lazy loading is done automatically.

Comment: @AudioGuy, I am glad that if worked. what is it that you cannot understand?

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was sent too early ;-)

Comment: @AudioGuy, LazyLoading works and loads data when you access property, for example if I want to get person details from database, *select query* will be sent for only person, **another select query** will be sent again if I want to access some *navigation property* of person, for example `person.Documents`